# How to convert Excel values to datetime format in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to extract data from an Excel worksheet using Excel Interop.  The cells in the used range here contain Date/Time values.  I've managed to get the values as text, but how can I convert this to a numeric or Date/Time format that can be used in comparison operations?

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        Excel.Range range;

        string str;
        int rCnt = 0;
        int cCnt = 0;

        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("Wind_Speed.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
        {
            for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= range.Columns.Count; cCnt++)
            {
                // here I can get a string value... how to make it date/time
                str = (string)(range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Text                                
                Console.WriteLine(str);
                Console.ReadLine();                       
            }
        }

        xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's really unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to convert strings into numbers? Into times? Something else? Can you demonstrate the problem *without* Excel being involved? Ideally, post a [mcve].

Comment: If you want to convert strings to other data types then look at the various `Parse` methods available for example int.Parse(string) / DateTime.Parse(string)

Comment: I totally agree with @JonSkeet: we would be glad to help, but please add some clarity to your question. In its current state it looks like you are trying to extract Date value from string (if so, it could be achieved by using either Parse(), or TryParse() or Convert() C# methods). Best regards,

Comment: The question is perfectly clear, it's just an X-Y question.  Converting from string is the wrong answer and removing Excel from the question removes the question entirely.  Converting from the Excel `Variant` value directly instead of through a string is the right answer here.

Comment: @J...: It may be clear to you - it's certainly not clear to me...

Comment: @JonSkeet I think OP's problem should be clear to anyone familiar with Excel interop.  I have to believe that I would include you among them.  The obviously ESL level of English could stand some improvement, and the code sample could probably be condensed a bit, for for a first post I think this is far better than most.

Comment: @J...: Well, all I can say is that it's *still* unclear to me. We don't know what kind of comparisons the OP is trying to perform, or what the data is. I'm glad it's clear to you, and hopefully you can improve the post, but it's genuinely still unclear to me (and it's been years since I've done any Excel interop...)

Comment: @J...: Your edit helps, if it's correct - but "The cells in the used range here contain Date/Time values" seems to be inferred just from the title. I'm not sure I'd want to make that assumption, even if it *may* be correct.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's the most logical conclusion and both the question and answer make sense and have lasting value in this state.  Agreed that OP may be trying to convert a string like `செவ்வாய்க்கிழமை, மதியம் நான்கு கடந்த கால் நவம்பர் 23.` into a `DateTime` value, and granted that would also make a good question, but I think OP and SO would be served well by having OP post that as a new question.

Comment: Hi guys,
First thanks for your quick help.
My main aim in my question is to write condition that compare between data time that i extract from Excel in Time column and time span i will decide ( like: 06:00 - 16:30)

Answer (score 7):

If the raw data is a "date" value in Excel (and not text) you should be able to pull the *value* and convert it to a DateTime using the [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
double dateValue = range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt].Value2;  // not "Text"
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(dateValue);
```

Also note that pulling data cell-by-cell using Office interop is usually much slower than if you pull all of the data in one big array then process the array in C#:

```
    range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    object[,] rangeDate = (object[,])range.Value;

    for (rCnt = 0; rCnt <= Array.GetLength(rangeDate, 0) ; rCnt++)
    {
        for (cCnt = 0; cCnt <= Array.GetLength(rangeDate, 1); cCnt++)
        {
           object value = rangeDate[rCnt, cCnt] ;

           ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really unclear what you are asking about, but probably you will need to obtain Value, not Text

```
//some code here
{
    var rangeValue = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Excel.Range).Value
    //do whatever you need 
}
```

Comment: Actually `Value2` is typically a better choice because it pulls the raw values for Currency and Date/Time cells, while `Value` does not.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Thanks!